# Printing Update query in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am facing problem with update query in Zend Framework. I want to only echo update query not executing and also try Zend's Get Profiler like

```
$db->getProfiler()->setEnabled(true);
$db->update('table', $data, $where);
print $db->getProfiler()->getLastQueryProfile()->getQuery();
print_r($db->getProfiler()->getLastQueryProfile()->getQueryParams());
$db->getProfiler()->setEnabled(false);
```

It help me but also execute the query. I want to print only update query.
please help me.

Comment: +1 kajal, had you tried to set getProfiler to be enabled ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will print all the queries

```
$db =Zend_Registry::get('db');
$db->getProfiler()->setEnabled(true);

$db->update('table', $data, $where);

foreach((array)$db->getProfiler()->getQueryProfiles() as $qry){
        $this->_qryProf     .=   "\r\n".print_r($qry,true)."\r\n";
    }

echo '<pre>';print_r($this->_qryProf);
die;
```

Comment: could not understand what are you saying?
what is meaning of starting of the action and ending of the action

Comment: where are you trying to print the query.?

Comment: I am not usigng MVC structure of zend only using lib of zend in project

Comment: Oh ok. Then you have to use the first part before your update query and the second part after your query.

Comment: Only update query is executing and not printing anything on browser

Comment: Have you used `die()` after printing the query.? do u have any error.?

Comment: I have updated my answer based on the code in your question.Try it.

Comment: ya it is working but also execute the update query that is not require when i am printing query.

Comment: I want to implement this in function. If i pass true as argument then update query should be execute else print update query.

Comment: Let me check @KajalSingh

Comment: Oops i think without executing the update query its not possible to log the query @KajalSingh

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39829/discussion-between-kajal-singh-and-user016)

Answer (score 0):

```
$db->getProfiler()->setEnabled(true);

// your code
$this->update('table', $data, $where);

Zend_Debug::dump($db->getProfiler()->getLastQueryProfile()->getQuery());
Zend_Debug::dump($db->getProfiler()->getLastQueryProfile()->getQueryParams());
$db->getProfiler()->setEnabled(false);
```